# python function. output a keys list from a dictionary if the key is todays date

Tags: python, dictionary, key

i import datetime module. but i'm not sure how to call it as a dictionary key.

````
def bad_food():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    past_due = {
        datetime.date.today(2020,11,24): ['chicken' , 'soup', 'chips'],
        datetime.date.today(2020,11,27) : ['lays', 'chilli'],
                }
    for key in past_due:
        if key == today:
            print (today.values())
print(bad_food())```
````

Comment: How does the posted code relate to your question?  What *is* your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare a tuple of the info you have provided for each key i.e., the `year`, `month` and `date` with the same subset of available info from `today`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> def bad_food():
...     today = datetime.datetime.now()
...     past_due = {
...         datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 24): ['chicken', 'soup', 'chips'],
...         datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 27): ['lays', 'chilli'],
...     }
...     for key in past_due:
...         if (key.year, key.month, key.day) == (today.year, today.month, today.day):
...             print(past_due[key])
...
>>> bad_food()
['lays', 'chilli']
```

Comment: awesome thank you for your help